# How to Use assets_ignore_folder_patterns on the config

Tags: assets

I would like to exclude multiple folders from the Asset list to minimize the amount of folders to be loaded.

I can't seem to get this config working. and there's not enough info available on the website.

Thank you.

Comment: what did you try? something like $config['assets_ignore_folder_patterns'] = array('/^cache'); ?

Comment: Good. I add this solution as answer, so we can close this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
$config['assets_ignore_folder_patterns'] = array('/^cache');
```